# MySQL bitwise NOT queries

Tags: mysql, bitwise-operators, bitmask

we have a bitmask column in our database, a bit like so
a, b, c, d, e, f, g
where a: 64, b: 32 etc...

No if I want users that have either a, b or c or any combination of those saved (with all other fields allowed to be 0 or 1) I query like

```
bit_column_name & 112
```

because 64 + 32 + 16 = 112

Now I thought the exclusion of users that have any of those options enabled would be

```
NOT bit_column_name & 112
```

but the query results I am getting don't seem to add up with the actual populations. I also tried `bit_column_name | 112` and `NOT bit_column_name | 112` which don't seem to fit either.

Any ideas what the proper bit query negation would be?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
`NOT bit_column_name & 112` returns users that only have exactly d or e or f or g but no combination of those

Answer (score 1):

yeah, ...
populations check out after all: `NOT bit_column & 112` is correct

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

`SELECT (112 & (~ bit_column_name)) AS target_users`

See [mysql related doc page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html)